# python temporary change of class default

Tags: python, default, temporary

I would like to temporarily change the default of a class. I came up with some ideas:

```
class C(object):
    VALUE_DEFAULT = [1, 2, 3]
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        if value is None:
            value = self.VALUE_DEFAULT
        self._value = value

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value


print("Initial default:", C().value)

"""
1) Repetitious version that makes code unclear if multiple
instances should be instantiated or the default should not be used.
"""
print("Changed default manually:", C(value=[0, 2, 4]).value)

"""
2) dangerously hard coded version
"""
C.VALUE_DEFAULT = [0, 2, 4]
print("Changed default by changing the default constant:", C().value)
C.VALUE_DEFAULT = [1, 2, 3]


"""
3) possibly more pythonic version
still this version seems hacky
"""
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def tmp_default(cls, name, value):
    old_val = getattr(cls, name)
    setattr(cls, name, value)
    yield
    setattr(cls, name, old_val)

with tmp_default(C, "VALUE_DEFAULT", [0, 2, 4]):
    print("Changed default with contextmanager:", C().value)

print("Restored the default again:", C().value)
```

From the possibilities above i strongly prefer 3). Any further ideas or improvements?

Thanks in advance

Comment: why not simply set the value you want when creating instances of this class?

Comment: Seems like this would make more sense with a factory.

Comment: @Haleemur I need to create loads of instances. So variant 1 is very repetitious.

Comment: @khelwood : good idea, though, i need to change the default multiple times. Thus i would end up with 100s of factories or again pass an argument which would would make creating the factory superfluous and even more chaotic.

Comment: It would cost you nothing to have hundreds of factories.

Comment: not computationally but it would produce lots of code.

Comment: @DanielBöckenhoff No it wouldn't. It would be less code than your other options.

Comment: @khelwood Then i probably have the wrong thing in mind. I though you were talking about adding a factory e.g. `@classmethod ¶def createWithDefault1(cls, value=new_default):¶ ...return cls(**kwargs)` Could you provide an example to show me what you mean?

Comment: @DanielBöckenhoff OK. I have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my suggestion, involving factories.

```
def make_cfactory(argument):
    return lambda : C(argument.copy())
```

I want to instantiate a bunch of `C` with the argument `[1,2,3]`, but I don't want to keep typing `[1,2,3]`. Instead of instantiating them with `C(...)`, I instantiate them using a factory.

```
cfac = make_cfactory([1,2,3])
c1 = cfac()
c2 = cfac()
c3 = cfac()
cfac = make_cfactory([100,12])
c4 = cfac()
c5 = cfac()
c6 = cfac()
```

`c1`, `c2` and `c3` have `value` of `[1,2,3]`.
`c4`, `c5` and `c6` have `value` of `[100,12]`.

If you pass other arguments to the `C` initialiser, you can add arguments to `make_cfactory` and/or to the lambda function.

Answer (score 2):

Having an optional keyword argument is the way this should be done in Python. Although, I want to point out a problem with your code.

```
class C(object):
    VALUE_DEFAULT = [1, 2, 3]
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        if value is None:
            value = self.VALUE_DEFAULT
        self._value = value

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

c1 = C()
c2 = C()
c1.value [0] = 10
c2.value # [10, 2, 3]
```

Since you assign the same mutable list as default value, updating `c1.value` updates `C.VALUE_DEFAULT`.

Here is how you could fix this.

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        # create a new array everytime
        self._value = [1, 2, 3] if value is None else value

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value
```

And whenever you need a value other than the default, you provide it as keyword `value`.

Alternatively, if you want to solve the mutability bug, but still use your other solution, you will need to `copy`.

```
import copy

class C(object):
    VALUE_DEFAULT = [1, 2, 3]
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        if value is None:
            value = copy.copy(self.VALUE_DEFAULT)
        self._value = value

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mutability problem. Your answer is my approach 1 though -  when removing the mutability problem.

Comment: I think approach 1 is the most Pythonic. But feel free to wait for another one if it does not suit you.

Comment: @Daniel Böckenhoff I added a way to solve the mutability problem for your other approach as well